# jQuery Cycle - track how many times each image in cycle is viewed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle

I have 3 jquery cycles on my website that I have randomised. The cycles can have any amount of images, as it is built dynamically. I would like to be able to keep track of how many times each image in each cycle is viewed.

Has anyone been able to do this? I have Googled for about an hour now and I've come up with nothing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: "I would like to be able to keep track of how many times each image in each cycle is viewed." In other words, count the amount of times an image is shown in the cycle and store that for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no in-built way to do something like this. But you can use the `before` callback to achieve something like this. The idea is maintain an global array and update count inside `before` callback. Check the following code

```
var viewCount = [];
$('#s2').cycle({ 
        fx:     'scrollLeft', 
        timeout: 1000, 
        before: function(){
          var index = $('#s2 img').index(this); 
          viewCount[index] = (viewCount[index])? viewCount[index] + 1 : 1;
});
```

**Demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/LPZxs/

[Cycle Plugin Options reference](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html)

Comment: Thanks Joy. That's what I'm looking for. Will just need to modify it to save to the database for that specific image.

Comment: @lc3m4n69 You are most welcome, Yeah it's generic, you have to modify to suit your need.